# Regex want to find all text containing several words using Regex

Tags: regex, rapidminer

I want to find all text snippets containing 1 or several words via regex. if I write finds(Text, "(?i)\blootbox|micro\b") it doesn't work, although it is syntactically correct.

Say, I have the following 2 sentences:

"I have lots of lootboxs at home"
"I have a micro brain"

The regex should return both these sentences, but it doesn't.

If I remove |micro, it only returns all snippts that contain lootbox, why is my OR operator not working?

Comment: Can you edit your code and give us more information about what you're trying to achieve? Give us a sample portion from the text that you are trying to work on.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because your `OR` is not checking for an encapsulated group. It's looking for `x` OR `m`. Resolve it by using a capture group (or non capture group if you prefer)

```
finds(Text, "(?i)\b(lootbox)|(micro)\b")
```